# Asymptotic Problem

Tags: asymptotics

Let us assume that $f(n)=2^{n+1}$, $g(n)=2^n$ be two functions.

Now, using limit to find $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n}$we get 2 as answer
2 is less than infinity, so $f(n)$ belongs to $\mathcal{O}(g(n))$.

But how is this possible as it can clearly be seen that $2^{n+1} < 2^{n}$.
using limits, $f(n)$ belongs to $\mathcal{O}(g(n))$ gets proved.

Comment: Because this is the definition of big O notation! $f(n) = O(g(n))$ if $|f(n)| \le M|g(n)|$ for some constant $M$. In other words, up to a constant, $f$ and $g$ "grow at the same rate".

Comment: can you please elaborate? I know the definition of Big O, that is why i dont understand how is 2^(n+1)<2^n

Comment: The Big Oh notation is about rate of growth. Both functions have the same rate of growth (an increment of $1$ in $n$ means $f$ and $g$ double). Some other funcions in $O(2^n)$ are $1000·2^n$ or $2^n + 10000$

Comment: Your function is $f(n) = 2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^n = 2g(n)$.

Comment: If I think I am understanding your question, the clarification is that $f  = O(g)$ does not imply that $f(n) \leq g(n)$.

Comment: yeah it is, 2g(n), so if both function have same rate of growth, does that mean that in such a case limit cannot be applied?

Comment: The logplot of these two functions for large $n$ may provide some intuition. [WolframAlpha](http://wolfr.am/1z7VWyq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Wikipedia**: Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions defined on some subset of the real
>   numbers. One writes
>
> $$f(x)=O(g(x))\text{ as }x\to\infty$$
>
> If and only if there is a positive constant $M$ such that for all
>   sufficiently large values of $x$, $f(x)$ is at most $M$  multiplied by
>   the absolute value of $g(x)$. That is, $f(x)=O(g(x))$ if and only if
>   there exists a positive real number $M$ and a real number $x_0$ such
>   that
>
> $$|f(x)| \le \; M |g(x)|\text{ for all }x \ge x_0$$

As you see:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=2$$

Then by limit definition given $\epsilon>0$ $\exists$  $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such:

$$\left| \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} -2 \right|<\epsilon  \ \ \ \forall n\geq n_0$$

Then:

$$\left| \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right|\leq \left| \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} -2 \right|+2\leq \epsilon+2  \ \ \ \forall n\geq n_0 $$
Therefore:

$$\left| \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right|\leq \epsilon+2 \ \ \ \forall n\geq n_0$$
$$\left| f(n)\right|\leq (\epsilon+2)\left|g(n)\right| \ \ \ \forall n\geq n_0$$